# SharePoint Hosting

Tags: hosting

I´m new in SharePoint and I wonder if anyone of you could recommend me a hosting for WSS 3.0 ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com) and [fpweb](http://www.fpweb.net/) are both known for their SharePoint hosting and help support the overall SharePoint community.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://sharepointhosting.uk.com they are part of a larger SharePoint Initiative so have some experts on hand should you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I second what Mike says.

I have used fpweb for a few clients. Despite a few hiccups in their early days, my personal opinion now is that they do a great job and are responsive if you need to contact support.

Have used Rackspace for non-SharePoint projects and I can say that they are also excellent and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Mike to go with Rackspace or FPWeb for Sharepoint hosting with one condition: you have a big budget to run your SP site. If budget it your constraints, you can consider cheaper and reliable alternative, such as ASPHostCentral (see http://www.asphostcentral.com/Windows-Sharepoint-2010-Hosting.aspx) or if you are looking for WSS 3.0 hosting, you can check http://www.asphostcentral.com/Windows-Sharepoint-3-Hosting-Plans.aspx).

Hope this helps :-)